# Ajax request parameter cannot be retrieved within servlet issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, parameters

As part of learning Ajax, I have created a little servlet + some HTML page + Javascript code. The page contains a couple of buttons. The idea is to pass a parameter value in a request according to the pressed button and return the value in the response. Nothing crazy.

Here is the function making the request (button are linked to this function on click):

```
function loadXMLDoc2() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/WebFront/Ajaxlet",true);
    var retr = this.id;
    var param = "cmd=" + retr;
    document.getElementById("L1_LEFT").innerHTML = param;
    xmlhttp.send(param);
}
```

The `L1_LEFT` element allows me to check the constructed parameter (for example: `cmd=bd_info`).

The following method is called on the servlet side to proceed the request and response:

```
private void setAnswer2(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

    Enumeration<String> iter = req.getParameterNames();

    System.out.println("Parameters=");
    while (iter.hasMoreElements()) {
        String next = iter.nextElement();
        System.out.println(next);
    }

    ...

}
```

However, each time I click on buttons, I get an extra parameter line printed:

```
Parameters=
Parameters=
Parameters=
Parameters=
...
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Following BalusC's solution, I modified my code as following:

```
var retr = this.id;
var param = "cmd=" + encodeURIComponent(retr);
document.getElementById("L1_LEFT").innerHTML = param;
xmlhttp.open("POST","/WebFront/Ajaxlet",true);
xmlhttp.send(param);
```

and

```
    Map<String, String[]> en = req.getParameterMap();

    System.out.println("Parameters=");
    for (String next : en.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(next);
    }
```

The GET solution works, but the POST solution does not work (same issue). I read that POST is preferable to GET. Anyone knows why POST would not work?

**EDIT II**

Here is the servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(name="Ajaxlet", urlPatterns={"/Ajaxlet"}, asyncSupported=false)
public class Ajaxlet extends HttpServlet {

    private void setAnswer2(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

        Map<String, String[]> en = req.getParameterMap();

        System.out.println("Parameters=");
        for (String next : en.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(next);
        }

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        out.close();        

    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("doPost");
        setAnswer2(req, res);

    }

}
```

**EDIT III**

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Ajaxlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Ajaxlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.test.Ajaxlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ajaxlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Ajaxlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/WebFront"/>
```

**EDIT IV**

Updated my `web.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 

    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Still having the same issue with POST.

Comment: I know you asked this question a while ago, but have you found an answer? Because right now, I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: No, not yet. I have been working on something else since.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a GET request and then sending the parameter in the request body. This isn't going to work. In order to send data in the request body, you have to create a POST request (and do the server side request processing job in servlet's `doPost()` method instead of `doGet()`):

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/WebFront/Ajaxlet", true);
xmlhttp.send(param);
```

On GET requests, you normally append the query string with the parameters to the request URL, not the request body:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/WebFront/Ajaxlet?" + param, true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Regardless of the request method, you should ensure that parameter names and values are properly URL encoded! You can use JS' builtin `encodeURIComponent()` function for this:

```
var param = "cmd=" + encodeURIComponent(retr);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I know that you're learning Ajax, but I suggest to after all take a look at an existing JavaScript library which takes all the nasty and cross browser sensitive details of sending Ajax requests and traversing/manipulating the HTML DOM from your hands, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com). In this related question you can find some nice examples how to get started with jQuery + Servlets: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Another unrelated note, you should prefer `getParameterMap()` to iterate over parameter names and values. It returns a `Map` instead of an old fashioned `Enumeration`; a `Map` allows you to use the enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: I am using/learning JQuery too. I got your GET solution to work, but the POST still does not work. I have updated my question. If you or anyone know why, I am interested. Thanks.

Comment: Did you implement the `doPost()` method?

Comment: Yes, and I double-checked it is called by adding an explicit print statement. I have been googling for other code examples, and it seems yours is correct. It could be something different at the Tomcat/NetBeans level.

Comment: Do you have an `@Override` annotation on the method? Does it compile with that annotation? Did you rebuild/redeploy/restart after editing the servlet class?

Comment: Yes, I have the override, it compiles, I clean/rebuild/redeploy and restarted Tomcat. Still the same issue. I put my servlet code in my question.

Comment: Well, maybe something in the request-response chain has consumed your request body (the one as obtained by `request.getReader()` or `request.getInputStream()`) before the servlet had any chance to parse the parameters out of it. Perhaps an overzealous logging filter or something? I'd also check with a HTTP traffic checker like Firebug's *Net* panel if the client has really sent the proper POST request body.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4314/discussion-between-jverstry-and-balusc)

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly this same problem, for documentations sake the solution was in my Javascript code,

When sending "form data" in your AJAX Post, you need to set a header like so..

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send("paramName=paramValue")`

source: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp